# Intellisense window is way too small

Tags: xcode

[image: Xcode Intellisense]

For some reason, I got this very tiny Intellisense window. It's so tiny that I can't get any help from what type a certain property needs, etc. Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that this is the height you getting for _every_ popup (and forced to scroll inside it)?

Comment: Exactly. I can only see only one line.

Comment: I would definitely file a bug report for this (you can also try this on a secondary display if you got one available and see if the same happens there before reporting it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to re-initialize the autocomplete suggestion to fix the window's dimensions issue:

1. Un-check `XCode` > `Preferences` > `Text Editing` > `Editing` > `Suggest completions while typing`

[image]

2. Restart XCode
3. Enable `Suggest completions while typing`